# Elegant fractions in one line

Tags: math-mode, fractions

What solution do you think is more elegant for a simple fraction that should be displayed in just one line?

My examples are

1. `$x_F \equiv \frac{p_z}{p^{\rm MAX}_{z}} = \frac{p_z}{\sqrt{s}/2}$`
2. `$x_F \equiv \frac{p_z}{p^{\rm MAX}_{z}} = \frac{p_z}{\sfrac{\sqrt{s}}{2}}$`
3. `$x_F \equiv \frac{p_z}{p^{\rm MAX}_{z}} = \frac{p_z}{^\sqrt{s}/_2}$`

This generates the following (using the `xfrac` package).

[image]

I don't like 2, but I also think that 3 is not very elegant.

Comment: How is `\sfrac` defined? Do you enable this command by loading a package?

Comment: Sorry @Mico I should have put the package [link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is nearly always best to use the slashed form for fractions in the text:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\( x_F \equiv p_z^{}/p^{\mathrm{MAX}}_z = p_z/(\sqrt{s}/2) = 2p_z/\sqrt s \)
\end{document}
```

Note that I have added brackets to the second fraction.

Comment: For some reason, the slash does not display as large as it shows in this solution (it doesn't have the same size as the surrounding elements). Have no idea why...

Comment: @capadocia  Hard to tell.  Compiling the displayed document under pdflatex or lualatex on my computer gives the shown output.  If you have loaded other packages, then the output is can be different as they may change the fonts.   It might be relevant to ask a new question, showing the set-up you are using.

Answer (score 56):

There is also [`nicefrac`](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac?lang=en) package which provides `\nicefrac{<Nr>}{<Dr>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
\( x_F \equiv \nicefrac{p_z}{p^{\mathrm{MAX}}_z} = \nicefrac{p_z}{(\nicefrac{\sqrt{s}}{2})} = \nicefrac{2p_z}{\sqrt s} \)

\vspace{.5cm}        %% Andrew's method for comparison purpose.
\( x_F \equiv p_z^{}/p^{\mathrm{MAX}}_z = p_z/(\sqrt{s}/2) = 2p_z/\sqrt s \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think, the slashed form looks better. In particular, it does not require to reduce the font size.