# Elegant fractions in one line for partial derivatives

Tags: math-mode, fractions

1. I've learned from the TeXbook and from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128498/1340 that textmode fractions are often best written in slashed form. Looking at my manuscript I just ran into `$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x}$`, but partial derivatives in slashed form seem to be much less common (though I've indeed seen them sometimes, but others dislike them too, e.g., see comment [How do I write the partial derivatives without partitioning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246863/how-do-i-write-the-partial-derivatives-without-partitioning#comment587091_246863)), especially when parentheses are needed.

   What's typographically appropriate there?
2. In fact, my actual code is `$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x, d_x}$`, because this isn't really calculus but some other notation (it's only inspired from partial derivatives) from a PhD thesis—which seems to never use slashed form. Still, if slashed form `$(\partial t)/(\partial x, d_x)$` is appropriate I could use it.

EDIT: I know the `, d_x` seems to make no sense—again, these are not actual partial derivatives. (I can link to the actual source but that's really off-topic).

Comment: choice of notation is normally considered off topic here, put personally I wouldn't use the `/` form for partial derivatives either `\frac` form or if inline use is more common switch to a `D_{xyz}` style of notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\frac{\partial t}{\partial x, d_x} \qquad \sfrac{\partial t}{\partial x, d_x} \qquad \sfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}\cdot\sfrac{1}{d_x}$

\end{document}
```

---

- The question is *probably off topic*.
- Anyway -- I like the slashed version better :).
- I do not understand the `,d_x` part -- are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Better use `\sfrac` from the `xfrac` package.  It remedies many of `nicefrac`'s shortcomings and `\sfrac` is less typing than `\nicefrac`.

Comment: Good idea. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: the (middle) slashed form doesn't look like it has the same meaning as the `\frac` form.  adding parentheses around the denominator would make them obviously equivalent.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, also my opinion. I just was out of time/motivation yesterday night.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the index notation.  This is somewhat common in physics.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[ \frac{\partial t}{\partial x, d_x} \equiv \partial_{x, d_x} t \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To be sure: that's probably `$\partial_x t$` (or `$\partial_{x, d_x} t$) based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Notation and on the  fact that `x` is the independent variables that `t` depends on (and `d_x`... sorry, don't ask). If so, I get it, and it seems a pretty clever idea.

Comment: @Blaisorblade Of course, you're right.  I messed up the order.  I fixed my answer.

Comment: Oh thanks—I was really wondering for a long moment!